# Trouble Converting C++ to MASM: find unique prime factors and amicable pairs

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, x86, masm

I have an assignment in my Computer Architecture and Assembly Language class where I have received the following C++ code, and have been asked to convert a portion of it into MASM assembly code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

#define MAXIMUM 1000000

int Factors[MAXIMUM];
int properFactors(int, int[], int&);

int main()
{
    int q;
    int numFactors;
    int pairCount = 0;

    clock_t startClock = clock();
    for (int p = 1; p <= MAXIMUM; p++)
    {
        q = properFactors(p, Factors, numFactors);

        if (q > p)
        {
            if (properFactors(q, Factors, numFactors) == p)
            {
                cout << "Amicable Pair: " << p << ", " << q;
                cout << "(" << q << " has " << numFactors << " factors : ";
                cout << Factors[0];
                for (int i = 1; i < numFactors; i++) 
                    cout << ", " << Factors[i];
                cout << ")" << endl;
                pairCount++;
            }
        }
    }

    double totalTime = (double)(clock() - startClock) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << "Number of amicable pairs found = " << pairCount << endl;
    cout << "Time = " << totalTime << " seconds" << endl;
}

int properFactors(int n, int factors[], int& numFactors)
{
    int i, k, sum, factor2;
    i = 1;
    k = 2;
    sum = 1;
    factors[0] = 1;

    while (k * k <= n) {
         if (n % k == 0) {
              sum = sum + k;
              factors[i] = k;
              i++;

              factor2 = n / k;
              if (factor2 != k) {
                   sum = sum + factor2;
                   factors[i] = factor2;
                   i++;
              }
           }
        k++;
     }

    numFactors = i;
    return sum;
}
```

The portion that I must convert to assembly is the following portion from the proper factors function:

```
    i = 1;
    k = 2;
    sum = 1;
    factors[0] = 1;

    while (k * k <= n) {
         if (n % k == 0) {
              sum = sum + k;
              factors[i] = k;
              i++;

              factor2 = n / k;
              if (factor2 != k) {
                   sum = sum + factor2;
                   factors[i] = factor2;
                   i++;
              }
           }
        k++;
     }
```

I have written the following assembler code to replace the code section above, but for some reason whenever I try to run the problem, the program will not output anything:

```
__asm {
        mov eax, 1                              ; i = 1;
        mov i, eax
        mov eax, i

        mov ebx, 2                              ; k = 2;
        mov k, ebx                          
        mov ebx, 1                              ; sum = 1;
        mov sum, ebx
        
        mov ebx, factors
        mov esi, 0
        mov [ebx + 4 * esi], 1                  ; factors[0] = 1;

        while_1:                                ; while (k * k <= n) {
            mov ecx, k
            imul ecx, k
            cmp ecx, n
            jle while_1_begin
            jmp while_1_end

        while_1_begin: 

            if_1:                               ; if (n % k == 0) {
                mov edx, n
                cdq
                idiv k
                cmp edx, 0
                je if_1_begin
                jmp if_1_end

            if_1_begin:
                mov esi, sum                    ; sum = sum + k;
                add esi, k
                mov sum, esi

                mov esi, k
                mov [ebx+4*eax], esi            ; factors[i] = k;
                inc i                           ; i++;
                mov eax, i

                mov esi, n
                cdq 
                idiv k
                mov factor2, esi                ; factor2 = n / k;

                mov esi, k

                if_2:                           ; if (factor2 != k) {
                    cmp factor2, esi
                    jne if_2_begin
                    jmp if_2_end

                if_2_begin:
                    mov edi, sum                ; sum = sum + factor2;
                    add edi, factor2
                    mov sum, edi

                    mov edi, factor2

                    mov eax, i
                    mov [ebx+4*eax], edi        ; factors[i] = factor2;
                    inc i                       ; i++;
                    mov eax, i

                    jmp if_2_end

                if_2_end:                       ; }

                jmp if_1_end

            if_1_end:                           ; }

            inc k                               ; k++;

            jmp while_1

        while_1_end:                            ; }
        
        mov i, eax
    }
```

Can anyone help me figure out why my program is not working correctly?

Comment: Step through it with the Visual Studio debugger.

Comment: Why do you do `cdq` right after `mov edx, n`? Why do you think that `eax` will be `i` in `mov [ebx+4*eax], esi`?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to expect that the division `idiv` operates on `EDX:ESI`, leaving its quotient in `ESI` and remainder in `EDX`. This is wrong! **The division `idiv` divides `EDX:EAX` by its operand and leaves the quotient in `EAX` and the remainder in `EDX`**.

In below rewrite I used capital characters where changes were applied. Compare what I have written with what you wrote and try to understand why the changes happened.

I made corrections and optimizations like removing redundant instructions. Please see how you can easily reduce the number of conditional jumps once you use the opposite condition.

```
__asm {
        mov  EAX, 2                             ; k = 2;
        mov  k, EAX                          

        DEC  EAX                                ; i = 1;
        mov  i, eax

        mov  sum, EAX                           ; sum = 1;
        
        mov  ebx, factors
        mov  [EBX], EAX                         ; factors[0] = 1;

        while_1:                                ; while (k * k <= n) {
            mov  ecx, k
            imul ecx, ECX
            cmp  ecx, n
            JG   while_1_end

            if_1:                               ; if (n % k == 0) {
                mov  EAX, n
                cdq
                idiv k
                TEST EDX, EDX
                JNZ  if_1_end

                mov  esi, sum                   ; sum = sum + k;
                add  esi, k
                mov  sum, esi

                MOV  EAX, i
                mov  esi, k
                mov  [ebx+4*eax], esi           ; factors[i] = k;
                inc  i                          ; i++;
                
                mov  EAX, n
                cdq 
                idiv k
                mov  factor2, EAX               ; factor2 = n / k;

                if_2:                           ; if (factor2 != k) {
                    cmp  EAX, K
                    JE   if_2_end

                    ADD  sum, EAX               ; sum = sum + factor2;

                    mov  ESI, i                 ; factors[i] = factor2;
                    mov  [ebx+4*ESI], EAX
                    inc  i                      ; i++;

                if_2_end:                       ; }

            if_1_end:                           ; }

            inc  k                              ; k++;

            jmp  while_1

        while_1_end:                            ; }
        
        mov  i, eax
    }
```